# Spring Integration reading from multiple file adaptors

Tags: spring-integration

I have multiple directories where I have inbound file channel adapters reading from. They all need to map to the same channel, but be able to pass the directory where the file is being read from to the channel. Help !!!

Answer (score 0):

The is no stops to configure the same `channel` for different `inbound-channel-adapter`s. And they may even be not only for file reading. But this is a different story.

For your `pass the directory` question:

No reason to do that from adapter perspective, because it returns exactly `Message<File>` where `payload` as a `File` object contains all required and desired properties.

P.S. Please, be sure that your questions in the future are properly formed and provide enough info for the community to understand your issue and have some insight to figure out where to dig for the answer for you. The words like "Help!!!" aren't informative and make moderators to close your questions and maybe ban you eventually...